string::rfind with count parameter fails to find the target char
I'm trying to find the last occurrence of a char in a range from a large text, so I have to specify off and count to limit the range.
string s = "a abc test";
cout << s.find_last_of(" ", 5, 2);//works, result 5

This works pretty well, but at first, I tried rfind().
I tried either rfind(" ", 5, 2) or rfind(" ", 3, 4), but both return npos.
Why?

Curious: from where did you get 5, 2, 3, and 4? I assume they make sense for one of the plethora of string search conventions in different languages, but at the moment, I see a possible explanation only for the 5. Besides, explaining your work in your question is a good idea. If you don't, you're expecting readers to understand your intent based on code that is demonstrably wrong.

The 2 methods are different:
std::string::find_last_of is used to:

Finds the last character equal to one of characters in the given character sequence.

(emphasis is mine)
Whereas std::string::rfind is used to find a given substring (not just one of its characters):
Also note that with std::string::rfind the count parameter determines the length (i.e. number of characters) of the substring to search for:

count     -   length of substring to search for

Therefore in order to find a string of 1 space character, you need to pass 1 for count.
std::string::rfind also has an overload that does not require count and simply serached for the substring as given.
In your case you can also use a 3rd overload that does not require a position and simply searches the substring from the right.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "a abc test";
    //---------------------------v---------
    std::cout << s.rfind(" ", 5, 1) << "\n";        // prints 5
    std::cout << s.rfind(" ", 5) << "\n";           // prints 5
    std::cout << s.rfind(" ") << "\n";              // prints 5
}

Output:
5
5
5

Live demo
(Note: the live demo is with gcc because Godbolt does not support an executor for MSVC at the moment, but I get the same result with VS2022).
A side note:
Your usage of count in find_last_of is also based on incorrect interpretation of the parameter (despite the fact that you got the expected result). It actually refers to the "length of character string identifying characters to search for", and not to the source string where the search is done.
And BTW - if you passed 3 or more as count it was also triggering UB (undefined behavior), because your s is " " which is char[2]:

If [s, s + count) is not a valid range, the behavior is undefined.


Unlike std::string::find_last_of - count there also sets the range in the first argument.

is determines how many chars to scan I suggest that you re-read the manual.

When differentiating the count argument of find_last_of and rfind it might be better to start by differentiating the functionality: find_last_of always searches for one character (any of the characters in the first parameter can be found -- this is where the "of" in "last of" originates), while rfind always searches for the entire first parameter. In both cases, count is the length of the first parameter.

@3CxEZiVlQ you are right. I stand corrected. Updated - I hope it is correct now.

@JaMiT thanks, I have now clarified that issue.

Your current usage actually invokes UB. This is not true. " " is const char[2] and 2 is a valid argument though the usage is a bit wrong.

@3CxEZiVlQ You are right. I actually added this sentence because of the other question by the OP, where count is big enough to invoke UB. Deleted the suffix (but left the comment in the other post).

Added info about usage that will cause UB, to emphasize the issue.

The count, third parameter in std::string::rfind 2) is the number of chars in the substring, first parameter. 4 is an invalid number for " ". 2 is valid and will search for  \0 that cannot be found in a abc test
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  const std::string s = "a abc test";
  std::cout << s.find_last_of(" ", 5, 2) << "\n";
  std::cout << s.rfind(" ", 5) << "\n";
  std::cout << s.rfind(" ", 3) << "\n";
}

Outputs
5
5
1

The first statement also does not do what you want. 2 sets the chars to search ' ' and '\0' from the string literal " ". You just don't have '\0' in "a abc test"s.

number of chars in the substring, the substring is extracted from "a abc test"?

No, from " ".
